# Woocommerce - Get price of product via AJAX from custom template page

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

Is there a way to retrieve a product's price via AJAX from a custom wordpress template (i.e. not a WooCommerce product page) if I know the ID of the product?

Comment: update your question... include codes of what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can..

```
$product = new WC_Product($product_id);
$product->get_price();
```

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly in PHP but how can I use this in a jQuery ajax call?

Comment: @user2562674 Please take a look at the link which they provide lot of examples of how to do with ajax https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins https://www.google.com/search?q=ajax+in+wordpress

Comment: I can't tell... it depends on how you are doing it @user2562674